# Owl carousel Slider-Is it possible to control via hover paginator instead of click paginator?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, owl-carousel

[blog]:is it possible to write like that or not

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    paginationhover: true//is it possible to write like that or not
});
```

Comment: You can use autoplay custom event and stop with stopOnHover (Stop autoplay on mouse hover). I don't know if you want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent two days but not found any forum to solve this issue. Finally i did this task by a shortcut function that is written by me. Hope it will helpful for you. Please check the code and modify it according to your requirement.

```
var slidercarousel = $(".owl-carousel");
  slidercarousel.owlCarousel({
    navigation : false,
    pagination : true,
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem : true,
    lazyLoad   : true,
    lazyFollow : true,
    lazyEffect  : "fade",
    autoPlay    : true,
    stopOnHover : true,
    addClassActive : true,
    afterInit: makePages,
    afterUpdate: makePages
  });

$( ".myslider" ).mouseover(function() {
    slidercarousel.trigger('owl.goTo', this.id);
    $('.myslider').removeClass('slider_active');
    $(this).addClass('slider_active');
  });

function makePages() {
    $.each(this.owl.userItems, function(i) {
    $('.owl-controls .owl-page').eq(i)
            .html("<div class='myslider' id='"+i+"'>"+$('.figureCaption'+i).html()+"</div>")
    });
  }
```

CSS FOR ACTIVE ITEM

```
<style>   
.home-page-slider .owl-controls .owl-pagination .active{
border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(161, 206, 42);
 }
</style>
```

For Demo Please go through this link and check it out. 
http://digishoppers.com/newhomepage

Comment: This fixed many issues I faced. I think this has all the things we wanted related to owl carousel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

```
    var owl = jQuery(".cd-hover-gal");
      owl.owlCarousel({
          items: 1,
          margin: 0,
          animateOut: 'fadeOut',
          animateIn:  'fadeIn',
          smartSpeed: 450,
      });
  jQuery(".cd-hover-gal .owl-dot").hover(function() {
      jQuery(this).trigger("click");
    }
  );
```

[see working example:](https://codepen.io/pascarel/pen/zXzMoy)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a more simple solution. I used arrive js to detect when the pagination elements were created and on mouseover I trigger mouseup

```
$(document).arrive(".owl-page", function () {
    var dot = $(this);
    dot.mouseover(function () {
        $(this).mouseup();
    });
});
```

https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive